# Keep from R8 obfuscating: inner classes or interfaces, where outer class extends or implements

Tags: proguard, obfuscation, android-r8

If I want to keep inner class, I use `-keep public class com.example.MyClass$MyInnerClass { *; }` (or `-keep public class com.example.MyClass$* { *; }` to keep any multiple inner classes).

**Question:** is there a possibility to keep all inner classes of a class, that matches signature by extending or implementing?

```kotlin
interface MyInterface { fun foo() }
```

```kotlin
class Foo : MyInterface {
  override fun foo() {}
  class Inner    // <- keep these with one rule for all `MyInterface` implementations
  class Another  // <- keep these with one rule for all `MyInterface` implementations
}
```

```kotlin
class Bar : MyInterface {
  override fun foo() {}
  class Third    // <- keep these with one rule for all `MyInterface` implementations
  class Fourth   // <- keep these with one rule for all `MyInterface` implementations
}
```

Something like `-keep public class (com.example.** implements io.foo.bar.MyInterface)$*`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use the following conditional keep rule:

```
-if class com.example.** implements io.foo.bar.MyInterface
-keep class com.example.<1>$*
```

If a class in package `com.example` implements `io.foo.bar.MyInterface` keep all its inner classes.